# Creating a dictionary from another dictionary keeping the structure intact

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsdictionary

I have a big dictionary with deep hierarchy in it... I want to read it and create another dictionary with same structure but with some modifications while I am reading the source dictionary.

Modifications are like if the keyName is "server" then remove that key, if the keyName is "notification" then alter its value.

What is the best way to do this keeping the structure of source dictionary intact.

Comment: What are you storing in your dictionaries? Strings?

Comment: @Nick: if it was just strings, there wouldn't be a "deep hierarchy".

Comment: @Josh Caswell I don't think that Abhinav is just storing dictionaries in dicts for the sole purpose of using them, there have to be some kind of data in the "leaves".

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Deep Copies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010162-SW3) section of [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034-BBCFIHFH). In fact, you should really read the entire document. You'll end up reading it all at some point anyway (or worse, having us repeatedly point you there), and it's only a few dozen pages.

I know this probably isn't the answer you were looking for, but the alternative is for someone here to code up a method that deep copies dictionaries for you. I'm not going to do that. If you get stuck on something specific, by all means, ask here.